# mocha chai expect error

Tags: mocha.js, chai

```
AssertionError: expected [] to equal []
Expected :[]
Actual   :[]
```

My test is this:

```
newJobFavored[key].should.equal(favJob[key]);
```

I upgraded all the packages recently and this broke. It appears it should pass if they are two empty arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`equal` on arrays just compares if it is the same object.

You need a deep compare with `eql` instead  of `equal` to compare content of the arrays:

```
newJobFavored[key].should.eql(favJob[key]);
```